# How to export database through putty?

Tags: mysql

I have large db so I want to export db by using putty.

Step -1 - connect to mysql

```
mysql -u username -p -- DBname
```

Then it will ask to input password. After putting password now my console is ready to execute mysql command

Step - 2 - to export db, I have tried

```
mysql -u username -p --dbanme > path/folder.sql
```

it's not working, I get error:

> showing ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  mysql -u griar_riar -p --griar_riar > path/folder.sql

I have also tried:

```
mysql -u username -p -- dbname > /path/folder.sql

mysql -u username dbname > /path/folder.sql
```

I have also tried mysqldump:

```
mysqldump -uuser_name -ppassword -hhost_name db_name > /path/folder.sql
```

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Comment: i have also tried by using mysqldump nut there is no success showing same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave out step 1 and use `mysqldump` directly on the shell, it is a console tool, not a MySQL command.

Answer (score 2):

Use mysqldump, it's the right tool:

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p NAME_OF_DATABASE > /path/to/file/export.sql
```

Substitute USERNAME, NAME_OF_DATABASE and /path/to/file/export.sql to fit your needs/enviroment.

mysqldump will require you to enter your password and then export your data.

If username is pigeon and database name is airport then this will export all your data

```
mysqldump -u pigeon -p airport > /path/to/file/export.sql
```

Comment: when i am trying to use the above query its showing below  error
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    206255
Current database: gdbanme

Answer (score 0):

```
> mysqldump -h your_host_name -P your_port_number -u your_user_name -p database_name > "/var/www/html/dbs/database_name.sql"
```

follow full syntax by providing hostname and port name it should works.